# Como volver a la pagina en la cual me loguee? Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que contiene una route llamada `/tramites` y otra `/control` para acceder a cualquiera de las dos tengo que estar logueado. El tema es que cuando me logueo siempre me lleva a `/tramites` y quiero que me redireccione a la pagina en la cual se esta logueando.
Por ejemplo:
Si voy a http://localhost:4200/tramites y me logueo, quiero que vaya a `/tramites`
Si voy a http://localhost:4200/control y me logueo, quiero que vaya a `/control`

Se que hay que usar guards pero soy nuevo en Angular y no se como aplicarlo.

mi auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private loginService: LoginService,
    private router: Router){}
    canActivate(){
      if(this.loginService.getToken()){
        return true;
      }else{
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }
    }
}
```